# How do I unwrap this element and append it to another?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to unwrap `.tweet-details` and append it to `.tweet-text`. Below is what I've gotten so far but for some reason `.tweet-details` isn't unwrapping.

```
<p class="tweet-text">This is a tweet.</p>
<p class="tweet-details"><a href="/">- Mar 21</a></p>

jQuery('.tweet-details').unwrap().appendTo('.tweet-text');
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you please add your complete markup ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The unwrap method removes the parent of the element it is called on. As the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) says:

> " Remove the parents of the set of matched elements from the DOM, leaving the matched elements in their place."

You might just need to do this:

```
$ ('.tweet-details').find('a').unwrap().appendTo('.tweet-text');
```

Comment: +1 Possible answer..Though its not clear the exact problem from OP

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery unwrap()](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) removes the element's parents from the DOM. Read this

> The .unwrap() method removes the element's parent. This is effectively the inverse of the .wrap() method. The matched elements (and their siblings, if any) replace their parents within the DOM structure.

So if `tweet-text` is the sibling to it, then it no longer exists in the DOM So you have to store its reference first before the unwrap operation. Do Something like this

```
var $a = $('.tweet-text');
$('.tweet-details').unwrap().appendTo($a);
```

[JSbin Demo](http://jsbin.com/pusoqaki/3/edit)

See this screenshot which shows its working

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `text()` if you are only ever looking for the content and no HTML tags:

```
var details = $('.tweet-details').text();
$('.tweet-text').append(details);
$('.tweet-details').hide();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RxgsX/1/